# Masterpage and Content pages inheriting from a single class

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, master-pages

I am trying to create a general class, in which all my ASP.Net pages inherit from so I can share functions across multiple pages.

To do this I would create a new class which inherits from System.Web.UI.Page (the content pages need to inherit this), and then my content pages would inherit the newly create class.

My problem is that the Masterpage inherits from System.Web.UI.Masterpage.

How can I set up my project so both content pages and Masterpage and use functions from the general class?

Please don't hesitate to ask if I am unclear!

Thanks!

E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, not sure why you'd want to do this. By their function Master Pages should mostly have functions that your Pages shouldn't be concerned with and visa versa. And if you just need some common functionality that isn't page dependent you can just create a static class (much like Math) or a helper class of some kind that you can implement in MasterPage and Page custom base classes.

But your only real option is to create two custom base classes. One that inherits MasterPage and the other from Page. Both will need to implement an interface ICommon which you create. Then create another static class that you can proxy all the functions to.

Yucky solution but it's the only one I can think of.

**EDIT**

Here's a better solution

```
public class Helper
{
   public static int getUserID(...)
   {
      // ... Code to get User ID
   }
}
```

In your masterpages and pages use

```
int UserID = Helper.getUserID(...);
```

Comment: I want to do this because I have many functions and data that I want to be able to use across web pages.  Without this, I will have to create a function getUserID, on every page that I want to get a user ID.  For Page specific functions, I will leave them in the CodeBehind file.

Comment: Since getUserID isn't page dependent you can just create a static class that they can both access. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, the MasterPage inherits UserControl and Page inherits TemplateControl. Like Spencer said, I would just create a Helper/Utility class.

Answer (score 0):

I know It's too late, but just want to share some one might come across the same.
This is a sample code using Extension functions:

```
public static void Commonfunction(this TemplateControl ctl)
{
      // Your Code here
}
```

Call this function as

```
this.Commonfunction();
```

in any Page or MasterPage.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is 5 years old, I wanted to share another option for future readers.

From what you explained, I suppose that what you call `MasterPage` is like a frame which loads the content page on a side of the screen, for example.

If I'm right, you can create a `BaseMasterPage` class with your functionality and then create a `MasterPage` for your content pages (which you could also use to place some of the code from your current pages). Next step is obviously to make both your current `MasterPage` and, let's say, `ContentMasterPage` inherit from this `BaseMasterPage`.

So this way you can end up having, for example, a `LoggedUser` property in both your frame page and content pages.